# Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer - Use Version 5 Instead of 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, .net-6.0

I'm testing out upgrading from ASP Core 5 to 6 on a small side gig (that makes a very small amount of money) and I can't afford to use Duende which replaces IdentityServer4 in version 6 of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer`.

I hope to continue using IdentityServer4 for now, and I found that keeping `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer` on version 5 while updating all the other ASP Core DLLs to version 6 works.  Is this a safe configuration?

- I know Duende is free for a year for me, but I'm worried that I won't be able to replace it within the year.

Comment: According to [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-6-and-authentication-servers/) _"The previous version of IdentityServer will continue to be supported for as long as .NET 5 is supported, until around February 2022."_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, its a safe configuration, but any change better wait for the November updating.